# How to use ASSERT to confirm the value of `current_user`

Tags: postgresql

While building up my schema (i.e., dev mode), I would like to use ASSERT to "confirm" that I'm doing what I think I'm doing.

I tried to use

```sql
create function api.login(...)
    returns void
    language plpgsql
    as $$
        declare
            ...
        begin
            ...
            ASSERT current_user::text = "anonymous", 'Unexpected user';
            ...
        end;
    $$;
```

Postgres renders the clause as a select statement and reports the error that `column "anonymous" does not exist`.  Right now, that's throwing me a bit given the like:

```sql
select (2 + 2 = 4)
> t

-- this does not generate an error
select current_user = 'db_user'
> t
```

I'm new to using Postgres (a. what took me so long?! b. and using sql outside of data processing :)), so would greatly appreciate learning the best way to assert the user is what I think it is (not to mention, conveying the security intent).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While that was not what was going on here, thank you for that potential "gotcha".

Comment: That's exactly what's going on here.  `"anonymous"` is an identifier, `'anonymous'` is a string constant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh.  Thank you for correcting me.  When I read the link I was "taken off course" by the unusual string concatenation that takes place between string constants separated by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

If I continue on with the given scenarios,

```sql
-- while the use of single quotation marks works
select current_user = 'db_user'
> t

-- use of double quotes infers a column value...
select current_user = "db_user"
> ERROR: column "db_user" does not exist
```

Got it.